# Modeling types and subtypes with strongly typed enums?

Tags: c++

I want to define a [ICMP header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol#Header) as a pod type:

```
struct ICMPHeader
{
    uint8_t   Type;         // ICMP type
    uint8_t   Code;         // Subtype, value is dependent on ICMP type.
    uint16_t  Checksum;     // Error checking data. See RFC 1071
    uint32_t  RestOfHeader; // Varies based on ICMP type and code.
};
```

For the `ICMPType` field I can use strongly typed enums to make it a bit nicer:

```
enum class ICMPType : uint8_t
{
    EchoReply              = 0,
    Reserved1              = 1,
    Reserved2              = 2,
    DestinationUnreachable = 3,
    SourceQuench           = 4

    // etc...
};

struct ICMPHeader
{
    ICMPType  Type;         // ICMP type
    uint8_t   Code;         // Subtype, value is dependent on ICMP type.
    uint16_t  Checksum;     // Error checking data. See RFC 1071
    uint32_t  RestOfHeader; // Varies based on ICMP type and code.
};
```

Now, I naturally also want to specify the `Code` field as an enum. It would be nice if I could use template specialization syntax, but a quick test reveals that it doesn't work:

```
// Compiler error
template<ICMPType>
enum class ICMPCode;    

template<>
enum class ICMPCode<ICMPType::DestinationUnreachable>
{
    DestinationNetworkUnreachable  = 0,
    DestinationHostUnreachable     = 1,
    DestinationProtocolUnreachable = 2
};
```

One option would be to wrap them in structs:

```
// Meaning of ICMP code is dependent on ICMP type.
template<ICMPType>
struct ICMPCode;

// Subcodes for DestinationUnreachable
template<> struct ICMPCode<ICMPType::DestinationUnreachable>
{
    enum class Code : uint8_t
    {
        DestinationNetworkUnreachable  = 0,
        DestinationHostUnreachable     = 1,
        DestinationProtocolUnreachable = 2

        // etc...
    };
};

// Access: ICMPCode<ICMPType::DestinationUnreachable>::Code::DestinationHostUnreachable
```

But doing it like this makes me feel that I'm just messing around and making things too complex..

I guess this is a specific example of a more general question: How to setup a system of types and subtypes? Any suggestions?

Ps:

- See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol#Header

Sample code:

```
#include <iostream>

// Trying to model ICMP types and codes with strongly typed enums
// See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol#Header


enum class ICMPType : uint8_t
{
    EchoReply              = 0,
    Reserved1              = 1,
    Reserved2              = 2,
    DestinationUnreachable = 3,
    SourceQuench           = 4

    // etc...
};


// Meaning of ICMP code is dependent on ICMP type.
template<ICMPType>
struct ICMPCode;


// Subcodes for DestinationUnreachable
template<> struct ICMPCode<ICMPType::DestinationUnreachable>
{
    enum class Code : uint8_t
    {
        DestinationNetworkUnreachable  = 0,
        DestinationHostUnreachable     = 1,
        DestinationProtocolUnreachable = 2

        // etc...
    };
};


ICMPCode<ICMPType::DestinationUnreachable>::Code GetReasonWhyDestinationIsUnreachable()
{
    return ICMPCode<ICMPType::DestinationUnreachable>::Code::DestinationHostUnreachable;
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(GetReasonWhyDestinationIsUnreachable()) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Posting code on external sites is frowned upon here on SO. I've moved it into your question..

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this statically at compile time because you're changing the `ICMPType` at run time.

I would suggest:

1. Make an enum for each of the `code` ranges you want to represent.
2. Create a container for each type (i.e. multiple `ICMPHeader` types specific to each type and lose the type variable there).
3. Create a factory which takes your original ICMP header and produces one of the specialised types with the appropriate `ICMPType` enum.

That should be a pretty flexible approach, but simply casting the value of the code depending on the type would probably be enough and much easier to handle.

In your example you just cast back to an int though which strips everything you just set out to achieve.. ?

*Edit - if all your containers inherited from a common base class you could gave a generic GetDescription() method which the children could then populate. Abstracting the details away like this makes for a nice clean design...*

Comment: You're right that the subtype can't be known at compile time so there has to be some runtime logic to go from ICMPType to ICMPCode. I think (2) and (3) are interesting ideas, I'll play with it a little.
Btw, I in the sample code I cast to int in order to print the numeric value, not the character.